# Lens zoom ambiguous variable

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm having difficulty using the `zoom` function given by `Control.Lens`. With my custom monad transformer `HearthMonad`, I cannot figure out how to satisfy GHC's "ambiguous type" complaint.

The code in question is in `drawCard`.

How can I solve this? Do I have to create my own custom zoom operator to handle the `Monad m` in `Hearth m`?

---

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}


module EngineZoom where


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


import Control.Applicative
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


type PlayerHandle = String


data Card = Card String
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)


data Player = Player {
    _playerHandle :: PlayerHandle,
    _hand :: [Card]
} deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
makeLenses ''Player


data GameState = GameState {
    _gamePlayers :: [Player]
} deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
makeLenses ''GameState


newtype Hearth m a = Hearth {
    unHearth :: StateT GameState m a
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState GameState, MonadIO, MonadTrans)


type HearthMonad = MonadIO


runHearth :: (HearthMonad m) => m ()
runHearth = evalStateT (unHearth runGame) mkGameState


mkGameState :: GameState
mkGameState = GameState { _gamePlayers = map mkPlayer ["Bob", "Joe"] }


mkPlayer :: PlayerHandle -> Player
mkPlayer handle = Player { _playerHandle = handle, _hand = [] }


runGame :: (HearthMonad m) => Hearth m ()
runGame = do
    card <- drawCard "Bob"
    liftIO $ print card


getPlayer :: PlayerHandle -> Lens' GameState Player
getPlayer handle f st = fmap put' get'
    where
        players = st^.gamePlayers
        put' player = let
            g p = case p^.playerHandle == handle of
                True -> player
                False -> p
            in set gamePlayers (map g players) st
        get' = f $ fromJust $ find (\p -> p^.playerHandle == handle) players


drawCard :: (HearthMonad m) => PlayerHandle -> Hearth m Card
drawCard handle = do
    let card = Card "Yeti"
    --getPlayer handle.hand <>= [card]
    zoom (getPlayer handle) $ hand <>= [card]
    return card
```

---

```
EngineZoom.hs:86:5:
    Could not deduce (Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom.Zoomed (Hearth m)
                      ~ Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom.Zoomed m0)
    from the context (HearthMonad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 drawCard :: HearthMonad m => PlayerHandle -> Hearth m Card
      at EngineZoom.hs:82:13-60
    NB: `Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom.Zoomed' is a type function, and may not be injective
    The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      drawCard :: PlayerHandle -> Hearth m Card
        (bound at EngineZoom.hs:83:1)
    In the expression: zoom (getPlayer handle)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      zoom (getPlayer handle) $ hand <>= [card]
    In the expression:
      do { let card = Card "Yeti";
           zoom (getPlayer handle) $ hand <>= [card];
           return card }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your newtype can only hold one state, namely `GameState`. Zoom essentially changes the state to the target of your lens, but since `Hearth` cannot have `Player` as a state, `zoom (getPlayer handle)` can't be used with `Hearth`.

The simple solution is to replace the newtype with `type Hearth = StateT GameState` and zooming works. If you want a newtype you'll need to have the state parameterised, here's an example:

```
import Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom

newtype HearthS s m a = Hearth {
    unHearth :: StateT s m a
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState s, MonadIO, MonadTrans)

type Hearth = HearthS GameState

type instance Zoomed (HearthS s m) = Focusing m
instance Monad z => Zoom (HearthS s z) (HearthS t z) s t where
  zoom l (Hearth m) = Hearth (zoom l m)
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. OP's problem was that he didn't have any pass-through Zoom instance to begin with, and we can solve that by writing the instance, and it's not necessary to generalize the state. `Zoomed (Hearth m) = Focusing m` and `instance Monad m => Zoom (Hearth m) (Hearth m) GameState GameState` is good here too. The `s` and `t` params in `Zoom` refer to the old and new state types of the monad transformer, not the type of the lens that can be zoomed.

Comment: @AndrásKovács You can write that instance but I can't get it to work. What would the type of  `hand <>= [card]` be? In my solution it's `HearthS Player m ()`.

Comment: You also can't write a `Zoom (StateT t z) (Hearth z) t GameState` instance because of the functional dependencies. You could do `Zoom (HearthS t z) (Hearth z) t GameState` where `HearthS` and `Hearth` are both newtypes but this feels like a bad solution.