# Lens: zooming newtype

Tags: haskell, zooming, haskell-lens, newtype

I'm interested in getting a *zooming* functionality for my monad transformer stack which is defined the following way:

```
newtype Awesome a = Awesome (StateT AwesomeState (ExceptT B.ByteString IO) a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad
           , MonadIO, MonadError B.ByteString
           , MonadState AwesomeState)
```

My *AwesomeState* is deeply nested record, so using zoom would greatly help me in updating some of the fields. But the problem is that zoom doesn't work out of the box for my newtype.

```
Couldn't match type ‘Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom.Zoomed Awesome’ 
with ‘Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom.Zoomed m0’
```

I found an example of how to make a custom newtype RWST instance of Zoom but trying to adapt it to my newtype gave me no results

The RWST example can be found here: http://lpaste.net/87737

Is there a way I could start using zoom with my monad transformer stack? What would I need to do in order to achieve that? If I should implement the Zoomed/Zoom like in RWST example then I need a pointer of how to do that because I tried and failed to do so.

Comment: This is  essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188217/lens-zoom-ambiguous-variable). I hesitate to vote duplicate though because this question is clearer than the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to make state of `Awesome` explicit:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, TypeFamilies,
    FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.Zoom
import Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom

data AwesomeState = AwesomeState
    { _someRecord :: String
    -- ...
    }

$(makeLenses ''AwesomeState)

newtype Awesome s a = Awesome (StateT s (ErrorT String IO) a)
  deriving ( Functor, Applicative, Monad
           , MonadIO, MonadError String
           , MonadState s)
```

Then you can define `Zoom` instance for it as follows:

```
type instance Zoomed (Awesome s) = Focusing (ErrorT String IO)

instance Zoom (Awesome s) (Awesome t) s t where
    zoom l (Awesome m) = Awesome (zoom l m)
```

Then you'll have

```
zoom someRecord :: Awesome String a -> Awesome AwesomeState a
```