# How to zoom a monad transformer?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, state-monad

thanks again for the help!

I'm making extensive use of the E. Kmett's Lens library, to avoid X/Y problems I'll explain a bit of context.

I'm working on an extensible text editor and want to provide extension writers with a monad DSL, an `Alteration` is a monad transformer stack with a StateT over the `Store` type, which basically stores the whole text editor. Inside the `Store` is an `Editor` which has `Buffer`s. Users can specify an `Alteration` to act over the whole store, but to simplify things I also provide a `BufAction` which operates over just a single buffer.

I was planning on implementing this by using a helper called `bufDo` which runs a `BufAction` over each `Buffer`, and a `focusDo` which runs a `BufAction` on the 'focused' `Buffer`. Here's some context:

```
data Store = Store
  { _event :: [Event]
  , _editor :: E.Editor
  , _extState :: Map TypeRep Ext
  } deriving (Show)

data Editor = Editor {
    _buffers :: [Buffer]
  , _focused :: Int
  , _exiting :: Bool
} deriving Show

data Buffer = Buffer
  { _text :: T.Text
  , _bufExts :: Map TypeRep Ext
  , _attrs :: [IAttr]
  }

newtype Alteration a = Alteration
  { runAlt :: StateT Store IO a
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState Store, MonadIO)

newtype BufAction a = BufAction 
  { runBufAction::StateT Buffer IO a
  } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState Buffer, MonadIO)
```

Here's my proposed implementations for `bufDo` and `focusDo`:

```
bufDo :: ???
bufDo = zoom (buffers.traverse)

-- focusedBuf is a Lens' over the focused buffer (I just 'force' the traversal using ^?! in case you're wondering)
focusDo :: ???
focusDo = zoom focusedBuf
```

This makes sense in my head and gets close to type-checking, but when I try to add a type for them I get a bit confused, ghc suggests a few things and I ended up with this, which is far from elegant:

```
bufDo :: (Applicative (Zoomed BufAction ()), Zoom BufAction Alteration Buffer Store) => BufAction () -> Alteration ()

focusDo :: (Functor (Zoomed BufAction ()), Zoom BufAction Alteration Buffer Store) => BufAction () -> Alteration ()
```

Which makes ghc happy for those definitions, but when I try to actually use either of them I get these errors:

```
    - No instance for (Functor (Zoomed BufAction ()))
    arising from a use of ‘focusDo’

    - No instance for (Applicative (Zoomed BufAction ()))
    arising from a use of ‘bufDo’
```

Looking around it seems like I may need to specify an instance for Zoom, but I'm not sure quite how to do that.

Anyone have ideas? I'd also love it if you could explain why I need a Zoom instance (if that's the case).

Cheers!

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407289/lens-zooming-newtype).

Comment: I saw that one, but was still a little confused, they give a solution, but don't explain it very clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a `Zoomed` type family that is used to specify what kind of "effect" we will have when we zoom. In some cases, the `Zoomed` type instance for a monad transformer appears to piggyback on the `Zoomed` for the underlying monad, for example

```
type Zoomed (ReaderT * e m) = Zoomed m
```

Given that `Alteration` and `BufAction` are just newtypes over a state transformer, perhaps we could do the same:

```
{-# language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# language UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}    

type instance Zoomed BufAction = Zoomed (StateT Buffer IO)
```

Then we must provide the `Zoom` instance. `Zoom` is a multi-parameter typeclass and the four parameters seem to be *original monad*, *zoomed out monad*, *original state*, *zoomed out state*:

```
instance Zoom BufAction Alteration Buffer Store where
    zoom f (BufAction a) = Alteration (zoom f a)
```

We just unwrap `BufAction`, zoom with the underlying monad, and wrap as `Alteration`.

This basic test typechecks:

```
foo :: Alteration ()
foo = zoom (editor.buffers.traversed) (return () :: BufAction ())
```

---

I believe you could avoid defining the `Zoom` instance and have a special-purpose `zoomBufActionToAlteration` function

```
zoomBufActionToAlteration :: LensLike' (Zoomed (StateT Buffer IO) a) Store Buffer 
                          -> BufAction a 
                          -> Alteration a
zoomBufActionToAlteration f (BufAction a) = Alteration (zoom f a)
```

But then if you have a lot of different zoomable things it can be a chore to remember the name of each zoom funcion. That's where the typeclass can help.

Comment: I'll try this out! Thanks! Would you be able to explain the `type instance` line a little more in depth? I haven't learned type families yet :P Also, why do we need undecidable instances? And lastly, why do I need both a type family `Zoomed` and the Zoom instance? I'd love to understand why it all works and why it's all required. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Chris Penner Type families are a bit like functions at the type level. They take a type (in our case `BufAction`) and produce another type (in our case `Zoomed (StateT Buffer IO)`). They have some particularities compared to regular functions: the syntax is not the same, the different "cases" can be dispersed in different modules, and so on. You can "run" a type family in `ghci` using the `:kind!` command, like `:kind! Zoomed (StateT Buffer IO)`.

Comment: @Chris Penner `UndecidableInstances` is required because when dealing with complex instance definitions GHC can be unsure about if typechecking can terminate. Turning on `UndecidableInstances` says "compiler, don't worry about non-terminating typechecking, if it takes too long I will just Ctrl-C and be done with it." It's not a harmful extension, if typechecking actually terminates, of course.

Answer (score 3):

As additional to the answer @danidiaz.

---

Basically, you can avoid `Zoom` instance by this way:

```
bufDo :: BufAction () -> Alteration ()
bufDo = Alteration . zoom (editor . buffers . traverse) . runBufAction
```

Comment: This works great! I appreciate the explanation along with @danidiaz's answer of course, it's nice to learn about type families finally! But is there any reason why I should use the type family wizardry instead of this solution?

Comment: Yes, it is, if you want to add possibility to use the `zoom` or somthing like the `zoomBufActionToAlteration`. This reason maybe (as wrote @danidiaz) if you have a lot of different zoomable things.